# Cast date to timestamp in pgSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp

Is there a way to cast a date to timestamp. For an example if I had a date like `2012/05/01`, how can I convert it to a timestamp like `2012-05-01 00:00:01`

Comment: Have you had a look at [Postgresql Data Type Formatting Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html)?

Comment: what have you tried which is'nt working. post that as well.

Comment: `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age) * 12 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM age) AS months_between
FROM age(TIMESTAMP '2012-06-13 10:38:40', TIMESTAMP '2011-04-30 14:38:40')`

I have a date variable and I need to replace this hard coded timestamp with the date variable @LohitGupta

Comment: @L.O.vanIngen Yes i looked but I couldn't find an answer there

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can cast the date column to text and then concatenate with the time portion of the timestamp.  In the query below I create a timestamp from the current date.

```
select (cast(current_date as text) || ' 00:00:01'):: timestamp
from yourTable;
```

Or if we already have a date type, we can simply add on the time component:

```
select current_date + '00:00:01'::time
```

**Output:**

```
11.07.2017 00:00:01
```

## Demo

**Update:**

If you just want the difference in months between two dates you can use the following:

```
DATE_PART('month', AGE(end_date, start_date))
```

Of course, there is no time component involved here, but assuming you were planning to assign the dummy `00:00:01` to both timestamps, the result would not change.

Comment: My stored procedure input variables are start_date and end_date. But this gives an error
`EXTRACT(YEAR FROM age) * 12 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM age) AS months_between
FROM age(TIMESTAMP 'cast(start_date as text) || ' 00:00:01'):: timestamp', TIMESTAMP 'cast(end_date as text) || ' 00:00:01'):: timestamp');`

Comment: It is giving an error because the code is wrong, you have unbalanced quotes in there.  Maybe update your question and let us know why you need to do this.  Normally you should not have to form a timestamp this way.

Comment: I need to get the month period from two dates. Could you please explain how to integrate my two variables in to this code?

Comment: Will it display the month difference of '2016-01-01' and '2017-02-01' as 13 ?
Or 1?

Answer (score 26):

You can convert it to a `timestamp` with this code:

```
SELECT current_date::timestamp
```

It will directly assign the time `00:00:00` to `current_date`.

Comment: It gives me this error. end_dates is my date variable
`ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "end_dates"
SQL state: 22007
Context: PL/pgSQL function gettargetreports(date,date)`

Answer (score 3):

```
select cast(current_date as timestamp) + interval '1 second'
```

Close to Standard SQL, only the interval syntax differs `interval '1' second`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add time part to date

```
select current_date + '00:00:01'::time
```